# how to add the placeholder value to ngmodel

Tags: placeholder, angular9, ngmodel

I am following an example in primeng in which I can add a new row to a table. Everything "seems" to work as long as I fill out all the fields in the input option. However, I want to add the place holder value to the NGmodel if the user does not change the value of the input. I tried everything (ng-init, ngvalue, etc etc) but I can never get the ngmodel to carry the value in the place holder... and the table gets fill with the 3 filled fields but not the one where the user did not type anything.
 extract of the HTML....

```
<div class="ui-g-12">
        <div class="ui-g-4">
            <label for="product_line_id">Product ID</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-8">
            <input pInputText id="product_line_id"  [ngModel]="myproduct.product_line_id"  placeholder="{{ lastproductline + 1}}" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-12">
        <div class="ui-g-4">
            <label for="product_line_1">Product</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-8">
            <input pInputText id="product_line_1" [(ngModel)]="myproduct.product_line_1" autofocus />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-12">
        <div class="ui-g-4">
            <label for="product_line_2">Category</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-8">
            <input pInputText id="product_line_2" [(ngModel)]="myproduct.product_line_2" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-12">
        <div class="ui-g-4">
            <label for="product_line_3">Sub Category</label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-8">
            <input pInputText id="product_line_3" [(ngModel)]="myproduct.product_line_3" />
        </div>
    </div>

the ts file looks something like...

productlines = [];
myproduct: { [s: string]: ProductLines; } = {};
showDialogToAdd() {
    this.newProductLine = true;
    this.myproduct = {}; 
    this.displayDialog = true;
  }

  save() {
    let productlines = [...this.productlines];
    productlines.push(this.myproduct);
    this.finalproductchanges.push(this.myproduct)
    this.productlinesClone = productlines;
    this.myproduct = null;
    this.displayDialog = false;
  }

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated
```

Comment: have you tried to set the value to your variables in ngModels to keep the values in the input? or simple add in yout html input a placeholder="mytext" ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to change the code by adding the field directly in the controller.